# I am getting this error while uploading Image

Tags: asp.net, .net

"This functionality requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. Please install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 to use this functionality."

If I install this, would it impact our project? I know there are several other link but not getting a proper answer.

I also install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 following this link:
 http://www.techhit.com/how-to/install-.net-3.5.1/windows7/

My code:

```
 <tr> <td class="FormCaption" style="WIDTH: 68px">Image</td> <td class="FormTableContainer"><asp:FileUpload CssClass="FormButtons" ID="questionImages" runat="server" Width="400px" /><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFilename" ></asp:Label></td> </tr>
```

Comment: When are you getting this exactly? Any code samples or scenario when you get the error is much appreciated. What is the current framework on the machine you are trying to run the code? Installing a framework shouldn't affect the functionality or project. However, it is good to upgrade deprecated functionality if you are using any.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You need to install .NET framework. It will not impact project.

Comment: I installed .. But still getting the error